# unable to save a bool variable using NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults, boolean

I am using XCode4.2 and developing and iPhone App

I ususally save data using `NSUserdefaults` (mainly strings ... )

I usually write the following two lines to save the data :

```
historyvar=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[historyvar setObject:boolVar forKey:@"bool"];
```

I am trying to save a BOOL variable but I get a red error when I do that :

```
Implicit converstion of'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
```

and I get a warning (yellow error)

incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'BOOL'(aka 'signed char') to parameters of type 'id'

is there anything equivalent to NSUserDefaults for Bool varibles ?
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a -setBool:forKey: method of NSUserDefaults.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:boolValue forKey:@"bool"];
```

and then you'll be able to get an *actual* BOOL value returned like this:

```
BOOL saved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"bool"];
```

This way you don't have to mess with NSNumbers.